# increase value of an element in array vba

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am working in VBA for Excel, and I have an array of integers.  What I am trying to do is add 1 to a specific element inside the array when my conditions have been met.  In my example code if the cell in column A is a 5 then I would like to add 1 in the 5th position of the array or if the cell is a 3 then add 1 to the 3rd position of the array.

```
Sub CountCustomers()
    Dim myArray(5)
    Dim i as integer
    For i = 1 to 10
        If Cells(i,1) = 5 Then
           myArray(4) = myArray(4)+1
        ElseIf Cells(i,1) = 3 Then
           myArray(2) = myArray(2)+1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

When I run it like this it ends up with a 1 in the correct position but will not increase the values any higher. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: That code doesn't compile. You need to remove the first `End If`.

Comment: `myArray(2) = myArray(2)+1` *is* the correct way to increment an array value by 1, so if the final value is less than you expect, this line is being executed less often than you expect. There is nothing about that line which stops the sum at 1.

Comment: Your array is created/initialized each time this piece of code is executed, so the values will start at zero. If you are expecting it to increase in-between different invocations, it wont. However, in a single invocation there is nothing that makes it stick at 1.

Comment: If your intention is to keep counts between runs, what you could do is change `myArray` from a local variable to a parameter of the sub. Do something like change `Sub CountCustomer` to `Sub UpdateCounts(myArray)`

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options below.

- Better to work with arrays for speed than loops (option 2)
- For this particular example you can use `CountIF` directly (option 1)

If you have multiple processing routes then `Select` can be more efficient than `Else If`

*code #1*

```
Sub Option1()
Debug.Print "number of 5's: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf([a1:a10], 5)
Debug.Print "number of 3's: "; Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf([a1:a10], 3)
End Sub
```

*code #2*

```
Sub Option2()
Dim x
Dim myArray(1 To 5)
Dim lngCnt As Long

'put range into 2D variant array
x = [a1:a10].Value2
For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(x)
    Select Case x(lngCnt, 1)
    Case 5
    myArray(4) = myArray(4) + 1
    Case 3
    myArray(2) = myArray(2) + 1
    Case Else
    'do nothing
    End Select
Next

Debug.Print myArray(4), myArray(2)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it's definitely good to have better and faster ways to make my code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as expected.  You should watch:[Excel VBA Introduction Part 3 - What to do When Things Go Wrong (Errors and Debugging)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DlqKfYTgc9Q&t=40s&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&index=3)

[image]
Here I set up watches to monitor your variables. The watches for `myArray(2)` and `myArray(4)` are set to break when there value changes.

[image]

Comment: Very good to know, I've been doing weird workarounds to try to get that kind of info, like printing out the values I'm looking at for every row in my file.  I'm kinda learning as I go.